# Prometheus - Not able to probe tcp end

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have setup prometheus and blackbox to check liveliness of my services and it is working fine for http targets but is not working for tcp one.

If i try to probe service using
curl http://blackbox:9115/probe?target=mongodb:27017&module=tcp

It gives me output as
probe_http_status_code 200
probe_http_content_length 84
probe_http_redirects 0
probe_http_ssl 0
probe_duration_seconds 0.310101
probe_success 1

but not able to get same result using prometheus job.
Prometheus UI shows status as DOWN with error "server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request"

Job configuration

```
    - job_name: 'mongo-service'
      scheme: http
      metrics_path: /probe
      params:
           module: [tcp]
      static_configs: 
              - targets: ['mongo-svc:27017']
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
        replacement: ${1}
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        regex: (.*)
        target_label: instance
        replacement: ${1}
      - source_labels: [ ]
        regex: .*
        target_label: __address__
        replacement: blackbox:9115
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine for me. Are you sure you're talking to the same blackbox exporter in both cases?

I'd suggest using tcpdump to see what the error is.

Comment: yes..prometheus is talking to same blackbox service. I will try with tcpdump

Comment: not possible to install tcpdump in prometheus pod.When i removed `metrics_path: /probe` , prometheus UI  shows status as UP for this service but with "/metrics " metrics_path (as /metrics is default uri)

Comment: tcp probe is successful with `module: [tcp_connect]`